# Running jQuery script after data loaded into table

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table that is loaded with values like so:

```
@foreach (var i in model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>i.value</td>
    <tr>
}
```

I want to add a CSS class to each of the cells in the table depending on i.value. My plan was to run a jQuery script with some conditionals like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
        var classToAdd = parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML, 10);
        if (classToAdd > 10) {
            cells[i].className = 'newClass1';
        }
        ... More conditional logic ...
    }
}
```

However, this is not working, and I believe it is because my script is running before the table is populated. If this is the case, how can I delay the script to run after the table is populated? Otherwise, please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How was C# related here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're using MVC...  you could add the class without javascript at all:

```
@foreach (var i in model) 
{
    <tr class="@(i.PropertyToCheck <= 3 ? "classOne":"classTwo")">
        <td>i.value</td>
    <tr>
}
```

Comment: Is there a more compact way to do that? Each iteration will be loading about a dozen td's and there are also about a dozen conditions to check, so applying it would become quite cumbersome.

Comment: I would suggest creating a helper and passing the model into the helper and returning a class from the helper. That should minimize your code and make it far more readible as well!

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor

@ThanksInAdvance - Here is a blog that should help you with creating a helper.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for.